# Do Flows in a Managed Package Count towards Flow Limits in Professional Edition Orgs

Tags: managed-package, governorlimits, isv, professional-edition

Professional Edition Orgs are limited to 5 active Flows / Process Builders.

If a Professional Edition org currently has 5 active flows, and I try to deploy a manage package that has X number of flows. Would those flows count against Org Limits?

I believe the answer is no, and therefore, the flows in the Managed Package will deploy in the target org, but I would like a clear answer on this. Thank you!

Comment: I would tend to agree with you ([doc](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_considerations_distribute_package.htm&type=5) suggests no issues). Of course the easiest way to find out is build an org w/ 5 flows then install a managed package that supports PE with at least 1 flow